# What is the Mandarin equivalent for the Shanghai term for dirty?

Tags: mandarin, character-identification, topolect, shanghainese

In the Shanghai dialect *dirty* is pronounced something like "o co" with the o pronounced like the "o" in *cot* and the "c" pronounced like the usual c in pinyin (kinda like an 'ts' sound).

Which characters would be used for writing these two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

龌龊  wò chuò
Meanings:
(1) dirty；filthy
(2) mean,despicable

It's not Shanghai dialect only. It's used a lot in northern China as well.

Comment: Thank you, so good to have some native speakers on this site!

Comment: No problems! It took me a while to realize it's 龌龊 too. :)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it's cognate to Cantonese 污糟 `wu1 zou1`. The tones would suggest not, though.

Comment: I think mandarin 龌龊 nowadays almost always has a connotation of poverty and even lack of space at home, but the Shanghainese word does not always (like `zu zi lo o co e` (桌子很脏)).

Answer (score 5):

As answered concisely by StarCub, 齷齪 龌龊 is the **Hanzi representation** for Shanghainese `o co`. Yet IMHO to call this word "the Mandarin equivalent" of `o co` is a bit **inappropriate**, since

1. from my understanding you are just asking for a Hanzi representation for a dialectal word, yet not its "equivalent" (or synonym, IMHO). A common mistake is to neglect the fact that any Chinese dialect can be a standalone system, **completely represented in Hanzi** yet **pronounced in a sound system different from Putonghua but still well organized in a way derived from ancient Chinese**.
2. though "dirty, messy" appears as one explanation for 龌龊 in modern Putonghua dictionaries, it's **far less frequently used** (from my daily experience) than the word's extended meanings "mean, despicable" or "narrow".

To add up, I'd like to mention 腌臢 腌臜 `a1 za1` in at least 贛 Gan dialect `nga41 tsa` is also a high-frequent daily word expressing "dirty". And the phonetic similarity among 腌臢 `nga tsa` in 赣, 齷齪 `o co` in 吴, 污糟 `wu tsou` in 粤 and 肮脏 `ang tsang` in Putonghua is really a interesting topic for further discussion.

Comment: +1 for your profound knowledge in the phonetically similar words across different dialects!

Answer (score 1):

髒？ zang1, which means 'dirty' or 'filthy'